# Should I do my annual evaluation if I hadn't received a raise in 5 years?

Tags: raise

I work for a non profit as an Executive Assistant. I have been here for 26 years and only make $35K right now. My last raise was 5 years ago. Since my raised I have been given numerous duties since my director took over 3 new senior centers. I am the one who orders the office supplies, furniture, phones, computers, deals with getting phones hooked up and fixed when needed, getting bids of heavy duty equipment and the list goes on. I asked my director for a raise up to $40K and she refused. She said that the Board Funding Raising account is in the red (which I know about since I have to take Minutes at Board Meetings). I feel so depressed and stuck. I survived cancer last year, but I still see my Oncologist every 3 months. He told me not to make any career changes until I reach my 3 year mark (so 2 more years). So my director asked me for my annual evaluation and I really don't want to do it! What would you suggest?

Comment: I'm curious, why does your oncologist not want you to make any career changes? Does he think the stress would be bad for you, or is he worried about medical coverage?

Comment: Can you do the evaluation during a normal 40 hr work week? If not maybe you can at least negotiate some extra money to do it.

Comment: If you've been at the same place for 26 years and you're only making $35k, you need to get a financial adviser to make sure you aren't working until you're 80.

Comment: What state and city do you live in?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere no, just offering a suggestion to the op that makes what sounds like a dire situation slightly more tenable. When you're making that little, even a few hundred $ extra can make a real difference.

Answer (score 28):

Do it.  Every year from now on.

It will lay the groundwork for a raise in the future.  It will chart/document increased responsibilities that you have assumed, and tasks that you have accomplished.  The funding won't always be in the red, and when the funding returns(back in the black) you have something documented to backup your request for a raise.  You're not just doing this b/c your boss told you to, you're doing it for yourself too.

On another note, it is handy to look back on when drafting a resume if you should decide to take that route.

Answer (score 7):

> So my director asked me for my annual evaluation and I really don't
>   want to do it! What would you suggest?

I assume refusing to comply with your director would be a bad career move.
And I assume asking for your annual evaluation is a regular (annual) thing. And I assume you have been performing your annual evaluation without first having had a raise for at least the past 5 years.

Thus, I suggest you do what you are told to do, or you may wind up on the receiving end of unintended career changes - despite the guidance of your doctors.

Have you felt depressed and stuck for 26 years? If not - what changed to make you feel this way? Examine your feelings to learn where they are coming from - that may lead you to feeling better, or to deciding what you want to do.

Comment: I doubt there will be unintended consequences. Where else will they find someone who can walk in the door and do all that for $35k (unless the locale is somewhere like extreme rural Mississippi)?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - Were? *Everywhere*. You seem to be forgetting that 35k is more than majority of humans will ever make during their entire life.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, someone willing to work for that will not have 26 years of experience. And any manager who doesn't know that probably deserves what he gets if he fires someone who does.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I meant a new hire, not the incumbent. There are a lot of reasons why someone would stay in a job they were hired for many years ago at what was then market rate where someone might not now walk in the door with that many years of experience. One of the chief attractions of job-hopping is that it's a way to get compensated for the experience you've gained in a way that you're unlikely to be compensated by staying.

Answer (score 2):

Do the evaluation.  Then when you sit down to discuss it with your director, explain that you want to see a path to a raise, and ask her what that path is.  Even if money is tight, they need to pay their employees properly, and a zero raise is really a 3% paycut due to inflation.  Pin her down and ask for a plan.  Don't threaten to walk out the door, but do make it clear that you need to be properly compensated.

You should also push to ensure it's not a (perceived) issue with performance or fit with the director.  During that discussion, particularly if she doesn't indicate a raise is likely, ask pointedly if your performance is above expectations, at expectations, etc.  Presumably your review will indicate this, but make it very clear.

This is the exact right time to discuss raises (evaluation time), so it's in your best interest to do it, and take it *very* seriously.  Lay out all of the exceptional things you did in the past year - **all** of them - as well as the regular duties that you performed.  Make it clear how good of an employee you are, and it's harder for your boss to justify giving you a 3% paycut [ie, no raise=inflation].

Answer (score 1):

At prima facia reading, I would say yes, do your paperwork and when it comes time to talk about your salary in earnest, you'll have a good footing.

However...  sometimes these evaluations can take a different meaning once you put your signature to them.  In the military (not from USA), you're asked to sign a review frequently.  The small print says that a signature means only that you've seen the above review, not at all that agree with it.  In reality, however, a signature is treated as tacit agreement with no further recourse permitted.

A good friend of mine, and a great officer, was given a poor review by a petty and jealous supervisor.  Because my buddy refused to sign the review, and refused to comply with illegal orders to do so, the review could never be filed.  The end result was that my buddy's grievances were taken seriously by his supervisor's supervisor.

If you feel this context applies to you, that submitting your review would be tacitly understood as anything other than what you mean it to, perhaps you should find a way to have your issues addressed before compliance.

Hope this helps.

Good luck with your cancer.

Answer (score 0):

The real question you should be asking yourself is why you're hanging on to this job.

You've already asked for a raise and have been turned down.  The company can only assume that since you've been working five years with no raise, AND then you asked for one and got turned down, that you must be fine with it -- reason being, you keep coming back to work!

If it's that much of an issue, *find another job* and quit trying to justify why this *one* little company owes you so much.  There's so much money flowing around the globe each day, and you can't **force** the company to recognize the work you do above and beyond your official job description.

They're not making a punk out of you at this point -- you're doing that all by yourself. :)